# No module named flask_sqlalchemy after deploying app GAE

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Iv'e been doing some maintenance on the server side and then deployed the app to the GAE. since I deployed the new version, it doesn't recognize the flask_sqlalchemy module. It worked perfectly before the commit. is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok for anyone getting this error, apparently I forgot to copy the libraries to the lib folder. I did that by using the command: pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt